# Remove date from text in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a dataset like the one below, and I would like to remove the date component from it. One challenge is that the date can be in different formats as shown below.

**Existing output**

```
Event A 05-25-2015
Event B 25-05-2015
Event C April 2015
Event D 2016
```

**Desired Output**

```
Event A
Event B
Event C
Event D
```

Comment: what is the query you are using to get the Existing output?

Comment: Will is always be in the format **Event X date** ?

Comment: If the leading part is always the same length ("Event A" = 7) you might just use `LEFT()`. Otherwise you must find a consistent rule, maybe after the second space. Where is this data coming from? How is it stored? And very important: Which RDBMS (vendor and version)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something to get you started. Depending on the number of formats that you might face, you might want to put them all into a table as patterns, join to that table, and use `LEN` to calculate values for the `STUFF` command.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (my_string VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @test (my_string)
VALUES
    ('Event A 05-25-2015'),
    ('Event B 25-05-2015'),
    ('Event C April 2015'),
    ('Event D 2016')

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', my_string) > 0
            THEN STUFF(my_string, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', my_string), 10, '')
        WHEN PATINDEX('%April [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', my_string) > 0
            THEN STUFF(my_string, PATINDEX('%April [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', my_string), 10, '')
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', my_string) > 0
            THEN STUFF(my_string, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', my_string), 4, '')
        ELSE my_string
    END AS my_string
FROM
    @test
```

My guess is that this is **very** error prone and might find false positives if someone has an event named, "Event 6421" for example.

This also only handles the formats that you had in your sample data. I would figure that you might need to handle more, but this should point in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much Tom H! The above solution worked perfectly and I was able to modify it for other date formats in my dataset. One more question; what if the date is in this format EventA - 12-09-2015? I want to remove the hyphen in front of the date as well and I am not able to do that. I tried adding it in brackets, but that didn't work.

Comment: The same method works fine for me. Double check that you changed the length parameter for the `STUFF` function. `STUFF(my_string, PATINDEX('%- [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', my_string), 12, '')`

Comment: Hi Tom H. That is exactly what i  did, but it seems that the Event still retains the hyphen at the very end. It is not working for some reason.

Comment: Ahh... just realized... you need to move that one up to the top of your `CASE` statement. When one pattern contains another you need the longer one at the top, because the `CASE` processes in order of the `WHEN` clauses. You need this one to be checked before it falls through and checks for the shorter pattern.

Comment: Tom H! That worked and the explanation makes sense! :) Thank you so much again, i really appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry one last question..what if the date format is like this January 2015 ? Can i use a variable in the Patindex to loop through all the months or is there an easier way to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here another way using `CROSS APPLY` should handle any format of data.

This will consider than you have **two space** in your data and extracts the data which is before the second space.

```
CREATE TABLE #strings
  (
     col VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO #strings
VALUES      ('Event A 05-25-2015'),
            ('Event B 25-05-2015'),
            ('Event C April 2015'),
            ('Event D 2016'),
            ('Event 4736765 2016')


SELECT Extracted_string = LEFT(col, pos2 - 1)
FROM   #strings
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex(' ', col)))a(pos1)
       CROSS apply (VALUES(Charindex(' ', col, pos1 + 1)))b(pos2)
```

**Result:**

```
Extracted_string
----------------
Event A
Event B
Event C
Event D
Event 4736765
```

Comment: Where is pos2 defined?

Answer (score -3):

Do you have the control to update the dataset? If so, update the dataset and separate the two columns. if not, use sub-string to chop out the event name.